# LINQ. Найти элементы, значения свойства которых совпадают со значениями, находящимися в коллекции

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Есть коллекция с неограниченным числом элементов, пусть для примера будут 3 имени

```
List<string> names = new List<string>()
{
    "Dmitry",
    "Katia",
    "Vova"
};
```

Предположим есть коллекция, хранящая сущности пользователей. Чтобы найти все сущности с именем "Dima" можно сделать что-то вроде этого `source.where(u => u.Name == names[0]).ToList();` А как найти всех пользователей, имена которых совпадают со значением элементов коллекции?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По-разному.

Например, можно сделать так:

```
var nameSet = new HashSet<string>(names);
var filteredUsers = users.Where(u => nameSet.Contains(u.Name));
```

(Можно, конечно, и обойтись без создания `HashSet`, но поиск по `HashSet<T>` выполняется за O(1), а поиск по списку — за O(длины списка).)

Comment: А разве `Intersect` сам не создаёт всё что нужно?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Там же разные типы у коллекций.

Comment: Тогда `GroupBy`?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Эээ, вот тут не понял. А какой будет синтаксис?

Comment: Хм.. `users.GroupBy(u => u.Name)` а дальше надо подумать...  Так, стоп. `from u in users join n in names on u.Name equals n select u` - так же? Что-то мы мудрим? Если так, надо будет потом ответ запостить)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Джойн — это изящно, да. Запости, кстати.

Comment: Запостил join :)

Answer (score 6):

Используйте метод `Intersect`.

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>
        {
            "john","sessian","rasul"
        };

        List<string> list2 = new List<string>
        {
            "john","mekka","rasul"
        };

        IEnumerable<string> Result = list.Intersect(list2);
```

А для **Entity** надо использовать интерфейс `IEqualityComparer<T>`.
(для entity объектов/моделих) здесь не видно но я определил: "Person -> Id ,                                                                      Name".

```
class PersonComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (x.Name == y.Name)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

IEnumerable<Person> Result = personList.Intersect(personList2, new 
                                                  PersonComparer());
```

Comment: Эээ, ТС спрашивает, как построить список entity, а не список строк.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо добавил.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что нужно будет создавать отдельный список Entity-объектов вместо списка имён?

Comment: @VladD компромисс , откуда знаете он только будет для имя (string - Name) использовать.

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
from u in users join n in names on u.Name equals n select u
```

при необходимости добавить `ToList()`:

```
(from u in users join n in names on u.Name equals n select u).ToList()
```

Вот код полностью: https://ideone.com/r04d1e

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class User
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var users = new List<User>
    {
      new User { Name = "John"   },
      new User { Name = "Katia"  },
      new User { Name = "Dmitry" },
      new User { Name = "James"  },
    };

    var names = new List<string> { "Dmitry", "Katia", "Vova" };

    List<User> res = (from u in users join n in names on u.Name equals n select u).ToList();

    foreach (var user in res)
      Console.WriteLine(user.Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: О, с первой шляпой!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста. А ваш вариант чем-то лучше, чем с использованием HashSet?

Comment: @mirypoko, не знаю. Вариант с HashSet хороший, зато у меня чисто linq одним выражением. Скорее всего, join внутри сам использует HashSet.

Comment: @VladD, не можешь тоже прокомментировать, что лучше?

Comment: @Qwertiy там Lookup внутрях

Comment: @PavelMayorov, поподробнее можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy особая прошитая хеш-таблица для хранения списков. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Lookup.cs

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а это лучше чем HashSet или хуже?

Comment: @Qwertiy по ресурсам - чуть хуже (более общий контейнер - больше накладных расходов); по аккуратности кода - наверное лучше если коллекция была получена из стороннего источника, т.е. если нельзя совместить ее получение с созданием HashSet.